# Find $z$ - complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Find $z$ if

> $\frac{z}{z+2} = 2 - i$

To solve this question, I used $a+bi$ in place of $z$. I finally arrived at the answer $z=-3-i$. This has been the case for many complex number questions. I usually substitute $a+bi$ and compare both sides of the equation. Is there any other more elegant or "smarter" method to do this question?

Comment: As the answers have already mentioned, the main thing is to *stop making it hard on yourself* by doing the extra step of looking at it with $a+bi$ $a,b$ real.  I know students are always tempted by "going back to something they're familiar with" by descending to real coefficients, but really there is no need for that.  The whole point of complex arithmetic is that you don't normally need to worry about what the real parts are. It bundles all that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done it as follows:\begin{align}\frac z{z+2}=2-i&\iff z=(2-i)(z+2)\\&\iff z\bigl(1-(2-i)\bigr)=4-2i\\&\iff z=\frac{4-2i}{-1+i}=-3-i.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiplying by $z+2$ we get
$$z=(2-i)(z+2)$$ so
$$z=2z-iz+4-2i$$ or
$$z(i-1)=4-2i$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

For example we can write

$$\frac{z}{z+2}=2-i \implies\frac{z+2-2}{z+2}=2-i   \implies 1-\frac{2}{z+2}=2-i$$

$$   \implies i-1 = \frac{2}{z+2} \implies z+2 = \frac{2}{ i-1} \implies z = \frac{2}{ i-1}-2$$

Then simplify the right-hand-side.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{z+2}z=\dfrac1{2-i}$

$\dfrac2z=\dfrac{i-1}{2-i}$

$-\dfrac z2=\dfrac{2-i}{1-i}$

Rationalize the denominator